# Proper locking for class that calls its own member functions from multiple threads. (Do I need to lock around accessing the "this" pointer?)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, valgrind

I am working on writing a multithreaded application and it currently has a class that spawns threads and then calls its own member functions from within those threads. I thought this would be fine as long as the member function itself doesn't use any shared resources, but when I ran `valgrind` with the `--tool=helgrind` option to detect data races and other thread related issues it complains.

**foo_main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class Foo final
{
public:
    void DoSomething() const
    {
        std::thread t1([&] {
            // Do I need to lock before accessing "this"?
            // std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
            this->Print();
        });

        std::thread t2([&] {
            // Do I need to lock before accessing "this"?
            // std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
            this->Print();
        });

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
private:
    void Print() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        std::cout << "TEST" << std::endl;
    }

    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.DoSomething();
}
```

Here is the output from valgrind:

```
valgrind --tool=helgrind ./foo
==27751== Helgrind, a thread error detector
==27751== Copyright (C) 2007-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP et al.
==27751== Using Valgrind-3.19.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27751== Command: ./foo
==27751==
TEST
==27751== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==27751==
==27751== Thread #1 is the program's root thread
==27751==
==27751== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==27751==
==27751== Thread #2 was created
==27751==    at 0x7848ACE: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==27751==    by 0x5051059: do_clone.constprop.4 (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==27751==    by 0x5052569: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==27751==    by 0x4C355BE: pthread_create_WRK (hg_intercepts.c:445)
==27751==    by 0x4C36A9B: pthread_create@* (hg_intercepts.c:478)
==27751==    by 0x531B596: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==27751==    by 0x401C94: thread<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0> (thread:135)
==27751==    by 0x401C94: Foo::DoSomething() const (foo_main.cpp:14)
==27751==    by 0x401480: main (foo_main.cpp:38)
==27751==
==27751== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==27751==
==27751== Possible data race during write of size 8 at 0xA6A6E18 by thread #1
==27751== Locks held: none
==27751==    at 0x4018FA: ~_Impl_base (thread:97)
==27751==    by 0x4018FA: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::{lambda()#1} ()> >::~_Impl() (thread:107)
==27751==    by 0x401508: destroy<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > > (new_allocator.h:124)
==27751==    by 0x401508: _S_destroy<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > > (alloc_traits.h:281)
==27751==    by 0x401508: destroy<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > > (alloc_traits.h:405)
==27751==    by 0x401508: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::{lambda()#1} ()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::{lambda()#1} ()> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() (shared_ptr_base.h:407)
==27751==    by 0x401CD0: _M_release (shared_ptr_base.h:144)
==27751==    by 0x401CD0: ~__shared_count (shared_ptr_base.h:546)
==27751==    by 0x401CD0: ~__shared_ptr (shared_ptr_base.h:781)
==27751==    by 0x401CD0: ~shared_ptr (shared_ptr.h:93)
==27751==    by 0x401CD0: thread<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0> (thread:135)
==27751==    by 0x401CD0: Foo::DoSomething() const (foo_main.cpp:14)
==27751==    by 0x401480: main (foo_main.cpp:38)
==27751==
==27751== This conflicts with a previous read of size 8 by thread #2
==27751== Locks held: none
==27751==    at 0x531B316: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==27751==    by 0x4C357B2: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:406)
==27751==    by 0x5051EA4: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==27751==    by 0x7848B0C: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==27751==  Address 0xa6a6e18 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 56 alloc'd
==27751==    at 0x4C2D7B8: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:422)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: allocate (new_allocator.h:104)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: allocate (alloc_traits.h:351)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: __shared_count<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > (shared_ptr_base.h:499)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: __shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > (shared_ptr_base.h:957)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > (shared_ptr.h:316)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: allocate_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > (shared_ptr.h:598)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: make_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > (shared_ptr.h:614)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: _M_make_routine<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > (thread:193)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: thread<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0> (thread:135)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: Foo::DoSomething() const (foo_main.cpp:14)
==27751==    by 0x401480: main (foo_main.cpp:38)
==27751==  Block was alloc'd by thread #1
==27751==
==27751== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==27751==
==27751== Possible data race during read of size 8 at 0xA6A6E28 by thread #1
==27751== Locks held: none
==27751==    at 0x4018FD: ~__shared_count (shared_ptr_base.h:545)
==27751==    by 0x4018FD: ~__shared_ptr (shared_ptr_base.h:781)
==27751==    by 0x4018FD: ~shared_ptr (shared_ptr.h:93)
==27751==    by 0x4018FD: ~_Impl_base (thread:97)
==27751==    by 0x4018FD: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::{lambda()#1} ()> >::~_Impl() (thread:107)
==27751==    by 0x401508: destroy<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > > (new_allocator.h:124)
==27751==    by 0x401508: _S_destroy<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > > (alloc_traits.h:281)
==27751==    by 0x401508: destroy<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > > (alloc_traits.h:405)
==27751==    by 0x401508: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::{lambda()#1} ()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::{lambda()#1} ()> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() (shared_ptr_base.h:407)
==27751==    by 0x401CD0: _M_release (shared_ptr_base.h:144)
==27751==    by 0x401CD0: ~__shared_count (shared_ptr_base.h:546)
==27751==    by 0x401CD0: ~__shared_ptr (shared_ptr_base.h:781)
==27751==    by 0x401CD0: ~shared_ptr (shared_ptr.h:93)
==27751==    by 0x401CD0: thread<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0> (thread:135)
==27751==    by 0x401CD0: Foo::DoSomething() const (foo_main.cpp:14)
==27751==    by 0x401480: main (foo_main.cpp:38)
==27751==
==27751== This conflicts with a previous write of size 8 by thread #2
==27751== Locks held: none
==27751==    at 0x531B325: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==27751==    by 0x4C357B2: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:406)
==27751==    by 0x5051EA4: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==27751==    by 0x7848B0C: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==27751==  Address 0xa6a6e28 is 40 bytes inside a block of size 56 alloc'd
==27751==    at 0x4C2D7B8: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:422)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: allocate (new_allocator.h:104)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: allocate (alloc_traits.h:351)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: __shared_count<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > (shared_ptr_base.h:499)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: __shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > (shared_ptr_base.h:957)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > (shared_ptr.h:316)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: allocate_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > (shared_ptr.h:598)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: make_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > (shared_ptr.h:614)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: _M_make_routine<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > (thread:193)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: thread<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0> (thread:135)
==27751==    by 0x401BEF: Foo::DoSomething() const (foo_main.cpp:14)
==27751==    by 0x401480: main (foo_main.cpp:38)
==27751==  Block was alloc'd by thread #1
==27751==
TEST
==27751== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==27751==
==27751== Thread #3 was created
==27751==    at 0x7848ACE: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==27751==    by 0x5051059: do_clone.constprop.4 (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==27751==    by 0x5052569: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==27751==    by 0x4C355BE: pthread_create_WRK (hg_intercepts.c:445)
==27751==    by 0x4C36A9B: pthread_create@* (hg_intercepts.c:478)
==27751==    by 0x531B596: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==27751==    by 0x401E96: thread<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1> (thread:135)
==27751==    by 0x401E96: Foo::DoSomething() const (foo_main.cpp:20)
==27751==    by 0x401480: main (foo_main.cpp:38)
==27751==
==27751== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==27751==
==27751== Possible data race during write of size 8 at 0xA6A6E18 by thread #1
==27751== Locks held: none
==27751==    at 0x40187C: ~_Impl_base (thread:97)
==27751==    by 0x40187C: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::{lambda()#2} ()> >::~_Impl() (thread:107)
==27751==    by 0x4014E6: destroy<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > > (new_allocator.h:124)
==27751==    by 0x4014E6: _S_destroy<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > > (alloc_traits.h:281)
==27751==    by 0x4014E6: destroy<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > > (alloc_traits.h:405)
==27751==    by 0x4014E6: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::{lambda()#2} ()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::{lambda()#2} ()> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() (shared_ptr_base.h:407)
==27751==    by 0x401ED5: _M_release (shared_ptr_base.h:144)
==27751==    by 0x401ED5: ~__shared_count (shared_ptr_base.h:546)
==27751==    by 0x401ED5: ~__shared_ptr (shared_ptr_base.h:781)
==27751==    by 0x401ED5: ~shared_ptr (shared_ptr.h:93)
==27751==    by 0x401ED5: thread<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1> (thread:135)
==27751==    by 0x401ED5: Foo::DoSomething() const (foo_main.cpp:20)
==27751==    by 0x401480: main (foo_main.cpp:38)
==27751==
==27751== This conflicts with a previous read of size 8 by thread #3
==27751== Locks held: none
==27751==    at 0x531B316: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==27751==    by 0x4C357B2: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:406)
==27751==    by 0x5051EA4: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==27751==    by 0x7848B0C: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==27751==  Address 0xa6a6e18 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 56 alloc'd
==27751==    at 0x4C2D7B8: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:422)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: allocate (new_allocator.h:104)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: allocate (alloc_traits.h:351)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: __shared_count<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > (shared_ptr_base.h:499)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: __shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > (shared_ptr_base.h:957)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > (shared_ptr.h:316)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: allocate_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > (shared_ptr.h:598)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: make_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > (shared_ptr.h:614)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: _M_make_routine<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > (thread:193)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: thread<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1> (thread:135)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: Foo::DoSomething() const (foo_main.cpp:20)
==27751==    by 0x401480: main (foo_main.cpp:38)
==27751==  Block was alloc'd by thread #1
==27751==
==27751== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==27751==
==27751== Possible data race during read of size 8 at 0xA6A6E28 by thread #1
==27751== Locks held: none
==27751==    at 0x40187F: ~__shared_count (shared_ptr_base.h:545)
==27751==    by 0x40187F: ~__shared_ptr (shared_ptr_base.h:781)
==27751==    by 0x40187F: ~shared_ptr (shared_ptr.h:93)
==27751==    by 0x40187F: ~_Impl_base (thread:97)
==27751==    by 0x40187F: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::{lambda()#2} ()> >::~_Impl() (thread:107)
==27751==    by 0x4014E6: destroy<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > > (new_allocator.h:124)
==27751==    by 0x4014E6: _S_destroy<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > > (alloc_traits.h:281)
==27751==    by 0x4014E6: destroy<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > > (alloc_traits.h:405)
==27751==    by 0x4014E6: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::{lambda()#2} ()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::{lambda()#2} ()> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() (shared_ptr_base.h:407)
==27751==    by 0x401ED5: _M_release (shared_ptr_base.h:144)
==27751==    by 0x401ED5: ~__shared_count (shared_ptr_base.h:546)
==27751==    by 0x401ED5: ~__shared_ptr (shared_ptr_base.h:781)
==27751==    by 0x401ED5: ~shared_ptr (shared_ptr.h:93)
==27751==    by 0x401ED5: thread<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1> (thread:135)
==27751==    by 0x401ED5: Foo::DoSomething() const (foo_main.cpp:20)
==27751==    by 0x401480: main (foo_main.cpp:38)
==27751==
==27751== This conflicts with a previous write of size 8 by thread #3
==27751== Locks held: none
==27751==    at 0x531B325: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==27751==    by 0x4C357B2: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:406)
==27751==    by 0x5051EA4: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==27751==    by 0x7848B0C: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==27751==  Address 0xa6a6e28 is 40 bytes inside a block of size 56 alloc'd
==27751==    at 0x4C2D7B8: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:422)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: allocate (new_allocator.h:104)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: allocate (alloc_traits.h:351)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: __shared_count<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > (shared_ptr_base.h:499)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: __shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > (shared_ptr_base.h:957)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > (shared_ptr.h:316)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: allocate_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > (shared_ptr.h:598)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: make_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> >, std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > (shared_ptr.h:614)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: _M_make_routine<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1()> > (thread:193)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: thread<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda1> (thread:135)
==27751==    by 0x401DAF: Foo::DoSomething() const (foo_main.cpp:20)
==27751==    by 0x401480: main (foo_main.cpp:38)
==27751==  Block was alloc'd by thread #1
==27751==
==27751==
==27751== Use --history-level=approx or =none to gain increased speed, at
==27751== the cost of reduced accuracy of conflicting-access information
==27751== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==27751== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 9 from 8)
```

When accessing a member function from multiple threads do I always need to lock BEFORE attempting access through the "this" pointer? Since it is a `const` member function it won't modify the object itself so I wouldn't think there would be an issue but `valgrind` is still giving me a lot of warnings.

In the real application I am working on the member function being called by the threads does quite a lot, so moving the code out of the member function and copying it everywhere I use it isn't really an option. But locking before even calling the function poses a problem because a lot of what is in the function could be done concurrently and preventing the portions of the function that don't use shared resources from running concurrently would significantly slow down the application.

Comment: did you try to lock before accessing this? Does this stop valgrind from complaining?

Comment: Yes it does, but it still feels like overkill since `Print` is a `const` member function and doesn't modify the object itself. Having to lock before every member function call would drastically slow down the application as a whole because very large sections of the code would block each other on different threads.

Comment: Replace `[&]` with `[this]`, then the threads get `const Foo* this`.

Comment: @273K just tried that and it still complains :(

Comment: In point of view valgrind, setting and reading `this` in your code happens in different threads and data race is possible. `[this]` should make copies of `this` in the same main thread and there's no data race. Is the code in the question the actual your code?

Comment: `~shared_ptr` and `make_sharad` in the callstacks are missing in the code. Thus, it's not an [mcve].

Comment: @273K The code in the example is the exact code I ran valgrind against. The `~shared_ptr` and `make_shared` must be happening underneath inside `std::thread` somewhere. Not sure where that is coming from.

Comment: Ok. Then I need to run it a bit later unless someone gets answer earlier.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Could you provide information on which version of Valgrind you are using [I see it is 3.19, is this a packaged version?], what Valgrind options, which version of GCC, compilation options and operating system?

Comment: I did manage to reproduce something with g++ 4.8.5.

Comment: @273K duh! did you look at the source for libstdc++ std::thread?

Answer (score 1):

This does look a bit like an old bug in libstdc++. This is the output that I get.

```
==27663== This conflicts with a previous read of size 8 by thread #3
==27663== Locks held: none
==27663==    at 0x4AD9056: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==27663==    by 0x40394FD: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:406)
==27663==    by 0x524ADD4: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==27663==    by 0x555CEAC: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
```

That looks like a raw read of memory. I don't have libstdc++ debuginfo so I can't tell where the '???' is. The callstack is in the new thread so I guess it's libstdc++ preparing to call the lambda.

Back in main, for the std::thread creation and shutdown, I see that libstc++ has switched from using std::shared_ptr to std::unique_ptr.

I'm pretty sure that the libstdc++ code is

```
   b5048:       eb d3                   jmp    b501d <_ZNSt11this_thread11__sleep_forENSt6chrono8durationIlSt5ratioILl1ELl1EEEENS1_IlS2_ILl1ELl1000000000EEEE@@GLIBCXX_3.4.18+0x16d>
   b504a:       66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

Entry point here:
   b5050:       55                      push   %rbp
   b5051:       53                      push   %rbx
   b5052:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp

Error here:
   b5056:       48 8b 07                mov    (%rdi),%rax
   b5059:       48 8b 5f 10             mov    0x10(%rdi),%rbx
   b505d:       48 c7 47 08 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,0x8(%rdi)
   b5064:       00
   b5065:       48 c7 47 10 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,0x10(%rdi)
   b506c:       00
   b506d:       ff 50 10                call   *0x10(%rax)
   b5070:       48 85 db                test   %rbx,%rbx
   b5073:       74 20                   je     b5095 <_ZNSt11this_thread11__sleep_forENSt6chrono8durationIlSt5ratioILl1ELl1EEEENS1_IlS2_ILl1ELl1000000000EEEE@@GLIBCXX_3.4.18+0x1e5>
```

The pointer is:

```
(gdb) p this
$80 = (std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Foo::DoSomething() const::__lambda0()> > * const) 0x582c058
```

That's the template class implementing the std::thread internal state implementation.

Comment: Well, as per my comment, I don't get an error with GCC 5 and later, so I didn't get a Valgrind callstack. I had to diff the 'thread' files. There have been lots of changes and the `thread` implementation has been moved to `bits/std_thread.h`. So I did a diff off the old `thread` and `bits/std_thread.h`. It's the "state" member that has changed from being a `shared_ptr` to a `unique_ptr`.